# Ubuntu fails to start after package installation

Tags: boot

I was installing graphics driver because my laptop PC was not detecting an external monitor, and after a reboot I haven't been able to start Ubuntu again. I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmzzH.jpg).

By entering recovery mode and starting as usual, I get [some more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgN0I.jpg).

I've tried uninstalling graphics packages from recovery mode, but I keep getting an error when I try to enable networking, something like 'Unknown username geoclue in message bus...'.

Some specs:

Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

Intel HD Graphics 630

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

I have Win 10 installed also.